# concatenating sysdate with fixed time in oracle

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic, sysdate

I want to concatenate `sysdate` with my own time. Below is the query i have tried, but I am getting year as `0016` instead of 2016.

Are there any other ways to get the result like below?

Query:

```
select to_date(sysdate || ' 02:50:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as MyTime from dual
```

Output:

### MYTIME

3/12/0016 02:50:00 AM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way

1. Convert SYSDATE to a string
2. Append your fixed time element
3. Convert back to a date

Put it altogether like this:

```
to_date(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')||' 02:50:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
```

Alternative way: use arithmetic.

1. Strip the real time from SYSDATE
2. Add the number of seconds `((60*60*2)+(50*60)/(60*60*24)`

Include your workings or not:

```
trunc(sysdate) + ( 10200 / 86400)
```

There is a third way: use an INTERVAL (basically a variant of the second way).

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate) + to_dsinterval('0 02:50:00') as mytime
  2  from dual
  3  /

MYTIME
------
2016-03-12 02:50:00

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') || ' 08:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
```

Just change `SYSDATE` to `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')`

I did this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
  TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') || ' 08:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS')
,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS') from dual;
```

and got

```
12-MAR-2016 08:00:00
```

as a result.